# In SQL database tables, why is redundant data generally a bad thing?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

And when is it necessary?

(for redundant data I mean same data in multiple tables)

Answer (score 5):

This is a broad question, but I think it has some succinct answers.

Redundant data is a bad idea because when you modify data (update/insert/delete), then you need to do it in more than one place.  This opens up the possibility that the data becomes inconsistent across the database.

The reason redundancy is sometimes necessary is for performance reasons.  Often, redundant data is simply easier to work with from a querying perspective.

Answer (score 2):

Disadvantages Of Data Redundancy:

1. Increases the size of the database unnecessarily.
2. Causes data inconsistency.
3. Decreases efficiency of database.
4. May cause data corruption.

Data redundancy in DBMS can be prevented by database normalization.

As mentioned previously by Gordon, redundancy is sometimes necessary is for performance reasons and recovery purposes.

Read https://major.io/2008/01/03/mysql-replication-redundancy/

for recovery using replication redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

1. For efficiency you must try to avoid repeating data on multiple tables.
2. For ease of coding you could duplicate some data and make a simple updater from one to other or something. It's like a cahe system :)
3. For repositories you do that as a safety precaution.

In that order I would remomend to avoid repetition  of data but not be paranoid about it and get too abstract if the project doesn't need it.
 That's only my opinion, of course.