# How do I send same data to 2 different tables?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jpa

I recently start learning JPA (as back-end for Angular 5 app) and met with one problem. I wanted to send same information basically for the same fields in different tables in one database. And it is been awful, because no solution I found on the web worked.

So, to explain in details:

Database test.
Table 1  - id, column 1, column 2, things, etc
Table 2 - id, things_1

So, here is a question - how do I store the date silmuteniously from one htm-form-field to things and things 1?

P.S. Maybe there is a way as well to get data to the multiple-choice field and then send the, directly to the Table_1, but if value of "things" were already same in the database, it wont store the value of "things" in Table 2?

P.P.S. Sorry for stupid question, just started to learn. Thank you and sorry in advance.

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="Table_1")
@SecondaryTable(name="Table_2",
                pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="Table_2_id", referencedColumnName="Table_1_id")
)
public class New{
 public New() {}

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name ="Table_1_id")
    private Long Table_1_id;

    @Column (name ="things", table = "Table_2")
    private String things;

    public Long getTable_1_id() {
        return Table_1_id;
    }

    public void setTable_1_id(Long Table_1_id) {
        this.Table_1_id = nfa_id;
    }


    public String getThings() {
        return things;
    }

    public void setThings(String things) {
        this.things = things;
    }
}
```

Comment: "*I wanted to send same information basically for the same fields in different tables in one database.*" - Why do you want this data redundancy? Normally, one strifes to avoid redundancy [and for good reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30657811/in-sql-database-tables-why-is-redundant-data-generally-a-bad-thing).

Comment: The other hint is to use a database transaction for such things. If you wrap both statements in a single transaction, you are guaranteed that either both statements succeed or none of them (atomicity).